# Some files cannot be deleted/modified in Far Manager

Tags: windows-10, permissions, ntfs, far-manager

I have Windows 10 machines where Far Manager started acting weird some weeks ago. In several folders, Far is unable to modify/delete files, which were not created by it. I have checked file attributes, NTFS owner and permissions and the files do not differ in anything. It is running under normal local Windows user, which is part of the local Administrators group and this user is the Owner of all these files.

The error in Far Manager is always first asking for administrative priviledges and when I approve that, it says "access is denied" anyway.

Today's experiments in the C:\Users\abc\Pictures folder:

- Text file created via Explorer's New menu and saved in Notepad cannot be deleted nor modified&saved in Far. However I can copy it to another folder, but cannot copy it in the same folder under different name.
- Text file created in the Far itself can be modified/deleted. When I rename such file in Explorer, it behaves suddenly as files from example 1 (cannot delete/save).
- Text file created in the Far itself can be modified/deleted. When I open the file directly in Notepad and save, it behaves suddenly as files from example 1 (cannot delete/save).
- Spawning "cmd" from within the Far Manager and deleting the file via `DEL` always works, which suggest that the actual user permissions are not the issue

I didn't do any changes to Far Manager for several years, Windows just updates itself, no new software installed recently. Today I tried to update to the latest version of Far Manager, but with the same results. My other PC with Windows 10 and Far Manager doesn't have this issue (but again, also this PC didn't have the issue few weeks ago).

Any idea how (in what) these files differ, so that one is editable by Far and the other is not? Can it be some corruption on the filesystem level? Or maybe some other console application which I could try to manipulate the files to see if the issue is only with Far?

Comment: Notepad had a big change a few years ago. It no longer opens, reads, closes the file, and when saving, opens, truncates, writes, closes the file. It now memory maps the file like a running executable is. This makes loading time of big files quicker. So if open in notepad it is in use on the disk.

Comment: @user1292580 thanks for the info, however with Notepad it was just a test, the issue is with pictures imported from phone and/or word documents saved from gmail or USB drive to local drive...

Comment: See what has a handle to it. Type `openfiles /local on` and reboot. When a file is locked type `openfiles /query` (it has options see `openfiles /query /?`).

Comment: As I've read the title I also thought of file system corruption, but it seems it isn't. Far Manager doesn't to something extra when working with files, it just calls the Windows API system calls. I would try to debug the issue with Process Monitor and also check if there is any malware installed that may hook into some user space / kernel functions.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end it was the AVG antivirus which was silently blocking FAR from modifying those files without any notice or information in the logs.
It is part of AVG's [Ransomware protection](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlName=AVG-Ransomware-Protection-FAQ&supportType=home), which protects *folders that may contain personal data*. In *Smart Mode*, it doesn't show the notifications about blocked modification attempts.

For some reason it decided to block FAR from modifying some types of files (mainly images and Word documents) in the My Documents subfolders. The solution is to add FAR to the [Allowed apps list](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlName=Use-AVG-Antivirus-blocked-allowed-apps&supportType=home). You can find it in Menu ▸ Settings ▸ General ▸ Blocked & Allowed apps. You need to browse for the FAR executable and allow it for *Ramsomware protection*.

[image]